# Unable get messages via Microsoft Graph API in postman

Tags: azure, postman, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

Good day

I follow this `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-postman` part of `Set up application API calls`.

I'm able to get users via API: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users`

but not able to get messages via API: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{ {UserId}}/messages`, it show me error below.

```
{
"error": {
"code": "AuthenticationError",
"message": "Error authenticating with resource",
"innerError": {
"date": "2020-06-28T06:16:03",
"request-id": "c0c3d9d5-9fa5-47a0-8b81-df85663ba297"
}
}
}
```

API Permission granted as below, could anyone advise how to fix above error?

[API Permission in Azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxNNa.png)

[Postman Request for get Token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOpWN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for sharing the request-id,timestamp(date) and postman Snapshot. Your application is an multitenant application and needs an additional step to get the permissions approved(admin consent). Here are the steps:

1. In the azure portal(portal.azure.com) navigate to the enterprise application.
2. Change the application type filter to "All application" and search for your application.
3. Click on the application name and click on the permission menu.
4. Click on grant admin consent for tenant (refer screen shot below).
5. After the above step, you will be able to get token with all the approved permissions.

[image]

**Personal Account**

Your application is preauthorized to read the messages (email) for the users within your tenant. Yours personal account (Microsoft Account) emails are stored your tenant context or any azure ad tenant context. To read personal account emails, application need to call /me/message graph API with delegated permission.

Comment: thank you @Dhivya G - MSFT Identity, I'm new to Micorsoft Graph, could you advise what i need to do on this case? 

the postman request body included ```scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default```

Comment: I update the the question to include the [Postman Request for get Token] for you reference, hope it helpful

Comment: I have updated the answer as per your query. Let us know if that helps.

Comment: thank you for your answer, 
i have done above steps, but seem still same error, 
please refer to screen below for detail.

[1. Admin Consent] [https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8c32.png]

[2. Postman get token] [https://i.stack.imgur.com/5u87S.png]

[3. Postman get messages] [https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIVuG.png]

Comment: Now your token has all the permission that your application has assigned. For the users you are trying to query message make sure that user has mailbox configured.

Comment: I just notice here is empty, is it the reason? because i tried in Graph Explorer with my outlook account, it able to send email, but in postman cannot. 

[User Profile in Azure][https://i.stack.imgur.com/00D3X.png]

how can i update it? i tried in Access Panel Profile [https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2003500], but cannot update.

Comment: To send email, you need to have Mail.Send application permission. Make sure your aplication has that.

Comment: thank you for your patience, and sorry make you confuse, in postman the get messages failed, here is response detail.

API: [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages]
Response: 
```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "AuthenticationError",
    "message": "Error authenticating with resource",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-06-30T07:37:34",
      "request-id": "ddbe6b1f-8b89-417d-a801-5a09a3426cb5"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: From the logs, i see that you are calling me/messages in application context. when you are calling api in application context, you need to call users/{id}/messages and not as me/messages.

Comment: thank you, but i just tried, refer to below,

API: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/ff74b6f0-34ab-4d39-894b-9df01aed2ab9/messages
```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "AuthenticationError",
    "message": "Error authenticating with resource",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-06-30T08:45:21",
      "request-id": "fd02371b-9d2f-4815-b5e2-9e3e6dbb5026"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: here is another request.

API: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/c4be245e-26e3-43aa-b29c-3d2d16a20450/messages
```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "AuthenticationError",
    "message": "Error authenticating with resource",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-06-30T08:46:14",
      "request-id": "d44548d5-27fc-4fae-8c7f-b20287a9fe46"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The user you are querying must mailbox setup meaning should have active license, etc. To confirm that try to access emails from https://outlook.office365.com/ by logging in with that user.

Comment: thank you, when i try to access outlook.office365.com with my personal account, it blocked and show me "You can't sign in here with a personal account. Use your work or school account instead."

and my Microsoft Azure is under this personal account.

does Graph Explorer work differently with Postman? because in Graph Explorer after i sign in that personal account, i'm able to get messages, how can i make it work in Postman also?

Comment: think Graph Explorer is using delegate access? means need user manual sign in to get token, then get messages on behalf of user, i'm able to achieve same in postman with on behalf of user, but Daemon Application cannot like that, is any workaround?

Comment: Your application is preauthorized to read the messages (email) for the users within your tenant. Yours personal account (Microsoft Account) emails are stored your tenant context or any azure ad tenant context. To read personal account emails, application need to call /me/message graph API with delegated permission. I update the answer with the same.

Comment: The first thing to do when you're getting authorization failures is to check your token. We have a handy parser tool at https://jwt.ms. Paste your token in there and look at the `roles` claim. What do you see listed there?